# displaying table header on both sides of a table

Tags: css, html-table

i would like to have the `<th>` fields of each row in my table to be displayed on *both* sides of the row.

E.g. my table looks like the following:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>8:00</th>
  <td>English</td>
  <td>Math</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

which will give me a nice header on the left-side of each row.
However, since the table can be rather wide, i would like to have the header repeated (on the right side).

It's easy to just add another `<th/>` element at the end of each row:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>8:00</th>
  <td>English</td>
  <td>Math</td>
  <th>8:00</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

However, I think that this is really not something i want to specify in my *content* but rather in the *stylesheet*.

So my question is: Is it possible to *automatically* (that is: by means of CSS only) repeat my `<th/`> element (or another element, like the first `<td/>`) at the end of my row (or column)?

Bonus points: Is it possible to *automatically* repeat the element at regular intervals in my row/column?

(i'm looking for a plain HTML solution. no JavaScript or other fanciness...)

Comment: can you not use `<th/>` element and use `td:first-child` and `td:last-child` instead?

Comment: @UKA i don't want to manually add that last element (whether it's `<th/>` or `<td/>`; i want it to appear automatically.

Comment: I don't see it as a stylistic thing. It is semantic content—it contains useful information you want to be available to the viewer.